# How can I move installed Django src and other djano apps to a new location(pip) in Ubuntu?

Tags: django, ubuntu, pip

I have installed Django and loads of other apps with it. I am using Ubuntu, and I didn't initially use `virtualenv` so all the Django stuff are in my `/user/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packagaes`. Whereas my project is in `Alex/workplace/projectx/src`. I have `Alex/workplace/projectx/projectx-env`. How can I move all my Django stuff from their installed location to my project `virtualenv` folder?

I am doing this because I want to install git in the project x so if I change something in one of the Django apps, I can merge them later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip freeze > dependencies.txt` while not in the virtualenv to get a list of all the installed packages in your system site-packages.  Pare the `dependencies.txt` file down to just what you need, and inside your virtualenv run `pip install -r dependencies.txt`.

This method lets you take a subset of the installed packages and also install them in the virtualenv.  This way is a whole lot safer than copying files from the system packages to your virtualenv's packages.

Comment: Thx. I am quite confused where to put my third-party apps. I know they have to be in PYTHONPATH but is it good practice to put them in my project folder or shall I make a folder external somewhere in my ubunto and use Symlinking? The thing is if I am using other apps, I want to svn/git them somewhere and use them,right? but when I svn up or get their latest commits from git, I dont want they break my project. So do I need to copy them again somewhere else and point my project to that?

Comment: The third party apps should also be installed into the virtualenv.  For a quick primer on pip+django+virtualenv+ubuntu, look at this article: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/